# Want to add all i's in the vector and then print the maximum value

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, integer

I just want to print all the elements in the vector when My if condition is true and all i's should be stored in the vector later on I want to print the maximum value of my vector please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> arr;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            arr.push_back(i);

    cout << arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Print vectors: `for (int v : arr) cout << v << '\n';` Print maximum value: `cout << arr.back();` (because larger `i` is always stored later in this example)

Comment: first i want to add the i's in my vector and then print the maximum sir

Comment: @Rohan It's the job of the OP to post their code properly here, you shpuldn't do such edits.

Answer (score 2):

Print elements of vector:

```
for (int v : arr) cout << v << '\n';
```

Print maximum value:

```
cout << arr.back();
```

(this will work because `1` will always be stored and larger `i` is always stored later in this example)

Print elements of vector (if you cannot use C++11 or later):

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++){
    cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

Print maximum value (of general vector):

```
if (!arr.empty()) {
    cout << *std::max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end());
}
```

Add `#include <algorithm>` to use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: with this code will all the i's get stored in the vector??

Comment: No. My code is just for printing vector. Adding `i`s is already done in your code.

Comment: thanks Sir and I apolozise for not typing out my code

Comment: a general vector requires `if (arr.size())` before dereferencing the iterator returned from `max_element`